# If I was to check if a network service Thunderbridge or Bluetooth was enabled how would I do that it in terminal?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, bluetooth, vpn

From Terminal, it lists that my MAC has six network services:

Bluetooth DUN 
USB Ethernet 
Wi-Fi  (also known as AirPort) 
Bluetooth PAN 
Thunderbolt Bridge
and VPN

My question is this: I want to check if the network services are enabled. How would I do this?

```
networksetup -getnetworkserviceenabled Wi-Fi
```

returns `Enabled` on the Mac, but checking for VPN or the other network services produces an error that reads: 
*NetworkService* is not a recognized network service.

So just for kicks, If I was to check for Bluetooth or ThunderBridge what would I call those things so that the terminal would understand the syntax?

Comment: This seems like a perfect X Y question. What is the overall context - what are you going to do based on the script results?